# How does img-responsive determine the appropriate size of images?

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsiveness

So I have two image being used in two locations.

Location 1:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-9">
        <a>
            <img alt="business card" class="img-responsive" src="/img/business_card_white.png"/>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <a>
            <img alt="printer" class="img-responsive" src="/img/printer_white.png"/>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Location 2

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <form autocomplete="off">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input placeholder="What are you looking for?" type="text" class="form-control" id="search" data-provide="typeahead" data-source='{{keywordsList}}'/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block{{#if entry}} btn-lg{{/if}}" style="margin-bottom:15pt">or just show me EVERYTHING!</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 center-block" style="margin-top:-9px;">
        <a>
            <img alt="business card" class="img-responsive" src="/img/business_card_white.png"/>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 center-block" style="margin-top:-9px;margin-bottom:4px;">
        <a>
            <img alt="printer" class="img-responsive" src="/img/printer_white.png"/>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The images themselves are big and 512x512 and bootstrap decided to scale it down in location 1 to 79x79. Strangely, with the addition of an input field and a button in location 2, the images get scaled down to 59x59.

This whole scaling thing seems arbitrary to me and I'd really appreciate it if someone could explain the logic behind it to me.

Comment: The  image width depend on boostrap column size, if your image is responsive it will occupy all the column width.

Comment: That makes sense. Location 2 is inside a col-md-10. If you turn it into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

The image width is dependent upon the column size. The reason for the discrepancy in image size between the two locations is because Location 2 was inside a `<div class="col-md-10">`.

What this did is it made the image smaller since the second location's width is 1/12 of 10/12 versus just 1/12 in location 1.

Comment: The grid, in essence.

Answer (score 1):

The image width depend on boostrap column size, if your image is responsive it will occupy all the column width